# tinyMCE in wordpress is not working in few computers and working in few

Tags: php, wordpress

i have got a very strange problem,in my office,we have over 10 computers and we write contents on wordpress,so visual editor is a commonly used tool of wordpress for us,But today we have transferred our wordpress from one server to another and after that,everything is working fine,but the TinyMce,thats the visual editor buttons(like b,i,and others) are not working in few computers,Any help regarding this would be appreciated.
Please note:
WE HAVE FEW MORE BLOGS ON THE SAME SERVER AND THEY ARE WORKING FINE.

in console::
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.newsyaps.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=358-23224
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined                 wp-langs-en.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined                 post-new.php:2215

Answer (score 2):

Its maybe late, but just an heads up for those have the same issues.

I also run into that problem once. When I check my cPanel error logs, it says:

```
[error] File "...public_html/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php" is writeable by group...
```

So what I did is to change the permission of the

> wp-tinymce.php

file from **755** to **644**

And those errors are gone :)

Cheers! 
**Neil**

Comment: In addition to what this comment explains, I had to change the permissions of the containing directories to 755. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)

Answer (score 2):

I am among those who tortured yourself with this [wp/tinymce/hosting] problem.

The purpose of `[wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php]`-file is to load this scripts:

```
[wp-includes/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js]
[wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/compat3x/plugin.min.js]
```

so if you have problem with the server/hosting
(for example, you do not have access to change directories/files rights or change .htaccess files)
You can always go the simple way and load the necessary tinymce files manually:

in your `[wp-content/themes/{YOUR_THEME_DIRECTOORY}/function.php]`-file add this:

```
function load_bloody_tinymce(){

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bloody_tinymce_js_main', includes_url() . 'js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bloody_tinymce_js_plugin', includes_url() . 'js/tinymce/plugins/compat3x/plugin.min.js' );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_bloody_tinymce' );
```

*Of course, this is not a solution to the access problem but if you are not a system administrator, it can help you.