# Correct file permissions for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, chmod

I've had a look over [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/) but didn't find any details on the best file permissions.  I also took a look at some of WordPress's form's questions over [here too](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-are-correct-file-permissions-1) but anybody that suggests 777 obviously needs a little lesson in security.

In short my question is this.  What permissions should I have for the following:

1. root folder storing all the WordPress content
2. wp-admin
3. wp-content
4. wp-includes

and then all the files in each of those folders?

Comment: Basically, only Wordpress uploads folder should be 777 but it would be a serious security threat. If you use a server with Suphp enabled, there is no need to modify permissions, manually.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is off-topic per the tag wiki excerpt: "Off-topic questions include those about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, server configuration, etc"

Answer (score 497, accepted):

When you setup WP you (the webserver) may need write access to the files. So the access rights may need to be loose.

```sh
chown www-data:www-data  -R * # Let Apache be owner
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  # Change directory permissions rwxr-xr-x
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  # Change file permissions rw-r--r--
```

**After the setup you *should* tighten the access rights**, according to [Hardening WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/) all files except for wp-content should be writable by your user account only. wp-content must be writable by *www-data* too.

```sh
chown <username>:<username>  -R * # Let your useraccount be owner
chown www-data:www-data wp-content # Let apache be owner of wp-content
```

Maybe you want to change the contents in wp-content later on. In this case you could

- temporarily change to the user to *www-data* with `su`,
- give wp-content group write access 775 and join the group *www-data* or
- give your user the access rights to the folder using [ACLs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists).

Whatever you do, make sure the files have rw permissions for *www-data*.

Comment: Plausible, if wp really only needs wpcontent. Do you have any references to substabtiate your thesis? This is SO not just chit-chat. Until now your comment is just a rant.

Comment: Kornel gives one such authoritative link below. See also http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions, Apache's doc http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/security_tips.html, and pretty much any google search on the topic. But in the general case, when in doubt, give no write access (and certainly no ownership) and loosen on a case-by-case basis, not the opposite (principle of least privilege which you're violating here).

Comment: I agree to the approach here. A permission set for "installation/upgrading" and a "hardened permission" set seems to be the best way to ensure both ease of upgrade, while providing security in an acceptable form.

Comment: Why is there an auto-update feature if it doesn't even work without changing the permissions??

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r, I see some PHP files under wp-content, are these really supposed to be writable by `www-data`??? That really sounds totally not secure at all.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: @AlexisWilke If you want WP to be able to self-update, then yes. If you want tighter permissions you can set that, but you'll need to update everything manually via ftp.

Comment: I think its important to set read-only access to `wp-config.php` and possibly also `.htaccess` files.  `chmod 444 wp-config.php` and possibly also `chmod 444 .htaccess`

Comment: A quick note: on my server, setting 755 permissions on a dir allowed directory listing to the world. Be careful with that. To prevent directory listing, you can use 751 instead.

Comment: This solution will prevent wordpress from installing 'automatic security updates'. You need to manually run the steps above for each minor wordpress update.

Comment: for the mac os user group is _www instead of www-data

Comment: `su www-data` will not work, you can not change role to this system user by design.

Comment: This is not a secure configuration. Setting read permissions on these files has no affect when the apache user also owns the files! DO NOT USE. Refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: On some hosting services, the server runs with the account owner's credentials and there's no way around it. No "www-data", no "nobody", no "apache", just user:user. If that's your case, you'll want to chmod all files to 0444 and folders to 0555 (yes, removing your own write permissions), save for the uploads folder, and only unlock them when you perform an update.

Comment: what about wp-content/uploads folder? after tighten the access rights can't upload image from admin panel.

Answer (score 60):

Giving the full access to all wp files to `www-data` user (which is in this case the web server user) can be dangerous. 
So rather do *NOT* do this:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R *
```

It can be useful however in the moment when you're installing or upgrading WordPress and its plug-ins. But when you finished it's no longer a good idea to keep wp files owned by the web server.

It basically allows the web server to put or overwrite any file in your website.
This means that there is a possibility to take over your site if someone manage to use the web server (or a security hole in some .php script) to put some files in your website.

To protect your site against such an attack you should to the following:

> All files should be owned by your user account, and should be writable
>   by you. Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be
>   writable by the web server, if your hosting set up requires it, that
>   may mean those files need to be group-owned by the user account used
>   by the web server process.
>
> ### `/`
>
> The root WordPress directory: all files should be writable only by your user account, except .htaccess if you want WordPress to
>   automatically generate rewrite rules for you.
>
> ### `/wp-admin/`
>
> The WordPress administration area: all files should be writable only by your user account.
>
> ### `/wp-includes/`
>
> The bulk of WordPress application logic: all files should be writable only by your user account.
>
> ### `/wp-content/`
>
> User-supplied content: intended to be writable by your user account and the web server process.
>
> Within `/wp-content/` you will find:
>
> ### `/wp-content/themes/`
>
> Theme files. If you want to use the built-in theme editor, all files need to be writable by the web server process. If you do not
>   want to use the built-in theme editor, all files can be writable only
>   by your user account.
>
> ### `/wp-content/plugins/`
>
> Plugin files: all files should be writable only by your user account.
>
> Other directories that may be present with `/wp-content/` should be
>   documented by whichever plugin or theme requires them. Permissions may
>   vary.

Source and additional information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Comment: *by your user account.* means the user executing the php scripts on the site (Normally the apache user) ?

Comment: @shasikanth No, the apache user is the one he refers to as “web server process”. User account is your Linux user (ssh, ftp user, etc.)

Comment: In this answer and in the accepted answer, should the user (not www-data) be part of the www-data group?

Comment: Nope, that is the whole point.

Comment: The problem I experience is anytime I make my SSH "user" the owner of /wp-content/plugins/, Wordpress becomes completely unfunctional from within the admin, with the constant FTP pop-up routine or permissions errors.  Cannot add, nor update plugins.  Only when I make www-data the owner of wp-content, does the Wordpress Admin plugin functionality work.  (Example:  sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/wp-content/)

Comment: @Heres2u: You could (temporarily) define FTP_USER, FTP_PASS, FTP_HOST in wp-config.php and WP will stop asking.

Comment: I'd like to reference the answer I provided here as an addition to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/wordpress-asking-for-my-ftp-credentials-to-install-plugins - it seems the file system checks WordPress undertakes when uploading plugins (for example) is leaning us towards having the same principal own the application files & run the php process. Thoughts?

Answer (score 26):

For those who have their wordpress root folder under their home folder:

** Ubuntu/apache

1. Add your user to www-data group:

CREDIT [Granting write permissions to www-data group](https://superuser.com/questions/646062/granting-write-permissions-to-www-data-group)

You want to call `usermod` on your user. So that would be:

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data yourUserName
```

** Assuming `www-data` group exists

2. Check your user is in `www-data` group:

   `groups yourUserName`

You should get something like:

```
youUserName : youUserGroupName www-data
```

** youUserGroupName is usually similar to you user name

3. Recursively change group ownership of the wp-content folder keeping your user ownership

   `chown yourUserName:www-data -R youWebSiteFolder/wp-content/*`
4. Change directory to youWebSiteFolder/wp-content/

   `cd youWebSiteFolder/wp-content`
5. Recursively change group permissions of the folders and sub-folders to enable write permissions:

   `find . -type d -exec chmod -R 775 {} \;`

** mode of `/home/yourUserName/youWebSiteFolder/wp-content/' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0775 (rwxrwxr-x)

6. Recursively change group permissions of the files and sub-files to enable write permissions:

   `find . -type f -exec chmod -R 664 {} \;`

The result should look something like:

```
WAS:
-rw-r--r--  1 yourUserName www-data  7192 Oct  4 00:03 filename.html
CHANGED TO:
-rw-rw-r--  1 yourUserName www-data  7192 Oct  4 00:03 filename.html
```

Equivalent to:

chmod -R ug+rw foldername

Permissions will be like 664 for files or 775 for directories.

P.s. if anyone encounters error `'could not create directory'` when updating a plugin, do:
`server@user:~/domainame.com$ sudo chown username:www-data -R wp-content`
when you are at the root of your domain.
Assuming: **`wp-config.php`** has
[FTP credentials on LocalHost](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57166/ftp-credentials-on-localhost)
`define('FS_METHOD','direct');`

Comment: -1. You do *NOT* want www-data to have write access to the wordpress files, except in wp-content.

Comment: 775 in wp-content does help. With 644 for files, 755 for folders, and chown user:www-data, I was sometimes still having problems with media upload, plugin update, etc. 775 allows wp-content to be altered by www-data:www-data as well, which solves the problem.

Comment: Remove the -R from the find/chmod command as it's slow and unnecessary.

Answer (score 20):

Best to read the wordpress documentation on this https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/

> - All files should be owned by the actual user's account, not the user account used for the httpd process
> - Group ownership is irrelevant, unless there's specific group requirements for the web-server process permissions checking. This is not usually the case.
> - All directories should be 755 or 750.
> - All files should be 644 or 640. Exception: wp-config.php should be 440 or 400 to prevent other users on the server from reading it.
> - No directories should ever be given 777, even upload directories. Since the php process is running as the owner of the files, it gets the owners permissions and can write to even a 755 directory.

Comment: Not sure why you got down-voted: it's almost as if people want the top answer to be how to leave the installation _insecure_!

Comment: Link is outdated. new one here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/ And thanks for being the only one referencing the actual docs!

Comment: If the wp-config.php is 400, how is the apache supposed to include it (thus read it) on page load?

Answer (score 14):

I set permissions to:

```
    # Set all files and directories user and group to wp-user
    chown wp-user:wp-user -R *

    # Set uploads folder user and group to www-data
    chown www-data:www-data -R wp-content/uploads/

    # Set all directories permissions to 755
    find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

    # Set all files permissions to 644
    find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

In my case I created a specific user for WordPress which is different from the apache default user that prevent access from the web to those files owned by that user.

Then it gives permission to apache user to handle the upload folder and finally set secure enough file and folder permissions.

**EDITED**

If you're using W3C Total Cache you should do the next also:

```
rm -rf wp-content/cache/config
rm -rf wp-content/cache/object
rm -rf wp-content/cache/db
rm -rf wp-content/cache/minify
rm -rf wp-content/cache/page_enhanced
```

Then it'll work!

**EDITED**

After a while developing WordPress sites I'd recommend different file permissions per environment:

In production, I wouldn't give access to users to modify the filesystem, I'll only allow them to upload resources and give access to some plugins specific folders to do backups, etc. But managing projects under Git and using deploy keys on the server, it isn't good update plugins on staging nor production. I leave here the production file setup:

```
# Set uploads folder user and group to www-data
chown www-data:www-data -R wp-content/uploads/
```

*www-data:www-data = apache or nginx user and group*

Staging will share the same production permissions as it should be a clone of it.

Finally, development environment will have access to update plugins, translations, everything...

```
# Set uploads folder user and group to www-data
chown www-data:www-data -R wp-content/

# Set uploads folder user and group to www-data
chown your-user:root-group -R wp-content/themes

# Set uploads folder user and group to www-data
chown your-user:root-group -R wp-content/plugins/your-plugin
```

*www-data:www-data = apache or nginx user and group*
*your-user:root-group = your current user and the root group*

These permissions will give you access to develop under `themes` and `your-plugin` folder without asking permission. The rest of the content will be owned by the Apache or Nginx user to allow WP to manage the filesystem.

Before creating a git repo first run these commands:

```
# Set all directories permissions to 755
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

# Set all files permissions to 644
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: Nooo! Never do a 777. Please don't advice this to (new) people reading this.

Comment: NO files or folders should be owned by the http process - this is a major security gap. If a malicious user found an exploit in a plugin or theme or wordpress itself they could upload code that can then be run by apache and gain access - i have seen it first hand :(

Answer (score 10):

Correct permissions for the file is 644
Correct permissions for the folder is 755

To change the permissions , use terminal and following commands.

```
find foldername -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find foldername -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

755 for folders and 644 for files.

Comment: and 640 for wp-config.php.But unfortunately, you have to change uploads&plugins&themes folders' permissions to 775 and if you wanna upgrade your wordpress then you have to change all folders to 775.In this section your permissions will pop up errors while upgrading/changing plugins,themes and uploading medias.

Answer (score 8):

I think the below rules are recommended for a default wordpress site:

- For folders inside wp-content, set 0755 permissions:

  **chmod -R 0755 plugins**

  **chmod -R 0755 uploads**

  **chmod -R 0755 upgrade**
- Let apache user be the owner for the above directories of wp-content:

  **chown apache uploads**

  **chown apache upgrade**

  **chown apache plugins**

Comment: You can also recursively set permissions for the directories, like:
**chown -R apache uploads**. And if required, you can also give the group ownership to apache: **chgrp apache uploads**

Answer (score 8):

It actually depends on the plugins you plan to use as some plugins change the root document of the wordpress. but generally I recommend something like this for the wordpress directory.

This will assign the "root" (or whatever the user you are using) as the user in every single file/folder, R means recursive, so it just doesn't stop at the "html" folder. if you didn't use R, then it only applicable to the "html" directory.

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html
```

---

This will set the owner/group of "wp-content" to "www-data" and thus allowing the web server to install the plugins through the admin panel.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content
```

---

This will set the permission of every single file in "html" folder (Including files in subdirectories) to 644, so outside people can't execute any file, modify any file, group can't execute any file,  modify any file and only the user is allowed to modify/read files, but still even the user can't execute any file. This is important because it prevents any kind of execution in "html" folder, also since the owner of the html folder and all other folders except the wp-content folder are "root" (or your user),  the www-data can't modify any file outside of the wp-content folder, so even if there is any vulnerability in the web server, and if someone accessed to the site unauthorizedly, they can't delete the main site except the plugins.

```
sudo find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

---

This will restrict the permission of accessing to "wp-config.php" to user/group with rw-r----- these permissions.

```
chmod 640 /var/www/html/wp-config.php
```

---

And if a plugin or update complained it can't update, then access to the SSH and use this command, and grant the temporary permission to "www-data" (web server) to update/install through the admin panel, and then revert back to the "root" or your user once it's completed.

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/html
```

---

And in Nginx (same procedure for the apache)to protect the wp-admin folder from unauthorized accessing, and probing. apache2-utils is required for encrypting the  password even if you have nginx installed, omit c if you plan to add more users to the same file.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd userName
```

Now visit this location

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/
```

Use this codes to protect "wp-admin" folder with a password, now it will ask the password/username if you tried to access to the "wp-admin". notice, here you use the ".htpasswd" file which contains the encrypted password.

```
location ^~ /wp-admin {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Now restart the nginx.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Comment: Using the root user is not recommended.it could be more dangerous Just make a new user n add him to sudo group

Comment: I didn't advocate here to use the root. I used the root as an example. you can use whatever any name instead of using the root.

Answer (score 2):

Commands:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R *
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Where ftp-user is what user you are using to upload the files

```
chown -R ftp-user:www-data wp-content
chmod -R 775 wp-content
```

Comment: should be chown username:www-data otherwise you can't edit files

Comment: You can use `$(whoami)` instead of `ftp-user`. By default, your current user (**not root**) is your FTP user if you are using your own server (local, vps, etc)

Answer (score 2):

To absolutely make sure that your website is secure and you are using correct permissions for your folders, use a security plugin like these:

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/

These plugins will scan your Wordpress installation and notify you about any potential issues. These will also warn you about any insecure folder permissions. In addition to that, these plugins will recommend you what permissions should be assigned to the folders.

Answer (score 2):

```
chown -Rv www-data:www-data
chmod -Rv 0755 wp-includes
chmod -Rv 0755 wp-admin/js
chmod -Rv 0755 wp-content/themes
chmod -Rv 0755 wp-content/plugins
chmod -Rv 0755 wp-admin
chmod -Rv 0755 wp-content
chmod -v 0644 wp-config.php
chmod -v 0644 wp-admin/index.php
chmod -v 0644 .htaccess
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you whether or not this is correct, but I am using a Bitnami image over Google Compute App Engine. I has having problems with plugins and migration, and after further messing things up by chmod'ing permissions, I found these three lines which solved all my problems. Not sure if it's the proper way but worked for me.

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

For OS X use this command:

```
sudo chown -R www:www /www/folder_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Define in wp_config file.

> /var/www/html/Your-Project-File/wp-config.php

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

chown - changes ownership of files/dirs. Ie. owner of the file/dir changes to the specified one, but it doesn't modify permissions.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the reading and agonizing on my own sites and after having been hacked I have come up with the above list that includes permissions for a security plugin for Wordpress called Wordfence. (Not affiliated with it)

In our example, the wordpress document root is 
    /var/www/html/example.com/public_html

Open up the permissions so that www-data can write to the document root as follows:

```
cd /var/www/html/example.com
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public_html/
```

Now from the dashboard in your site, as an admin you can perform updates.

Secure Site after Updates are finished by following these steps:

```
sudo chown -R wp-user:wp-user public_html/
```

The above command changes permissions of everything in the wordpress install to the wordpress FTP user.

```
cd public_html/wp-content
sudo chown -R www-data:wp-user wflogs
sudo chown -R www-data:wp-user uploads
```

The above command ensures that the security plugin Wordfence has access to its logs. The uploads directory is also writeable by www-data.

```
cd plugins
sudo chown -R www-data:wp-user wordfence/
```

The above command also ensures that the security plugin has required read write access for its proper function.

Directory and Files Permissions

```
# Set all directories permissions to 755
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

# Set all files permissions to 644
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Set the permissions for wp-config.php to 640 so that only wp-user can read this file and no one else. Permissions of 440 didn't work for me with above file ownership.

```
sudo chmod 640 wp-config.php
```

Wordpress automatic updates using SSH were working with fine with PHP5 but broke with PHP7.0 due to problems with php7.0-ssh2 bundeld with Ubuntu 16.04 and I couldn't find how to install the right version and make it work. Fortunately a very reliable plugin called [ssh-sftp-updater-support](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/) (free) makes automatic updates using SFTP possible without need for libssh2. So the above permissions never have to be loosened except in rare cases as needed.