# Could not remove the old plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permissions, file-permissions, plesk

I'm trying to update the plugins on my clients site and I'm getting this error for multiple plugins. He's using plesk.

```
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/awesometastic.131026.zip…
Unpacking the update…
Installing the latest version…
Removing the old version of the plugin…
Plugin update failed.


An error occurred while updating Awesometastic Plugin: Could not remove the old plugin.
```

I'm sure it's got something to do with directory permissions, although, could someone explain to me what the possible issues are and how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check domain's error_log (you can do it from plesk UI or download it from via FTP)

Comment: I had the same issue:

** Using ubuntu command line

[Correct file permissions for wordpress][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress/26438997#26438997

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Open FTP ank kill em all :)
Then reinstall those plugins. It is better not to open admin panel while removed so you have it still activated.

But do backup. It can Save Willy

Answer (score 17):

It's a permissions issue. Run this on SSH:

```
chmod -R 0755 /var/www/<yourpathtowordpress>/wp-content/plugins

chown -R www-data /var/www/<yourpathtowordpress>/wp-content/plugins
```

The first grants writing permissions, while the second ensures the user who needs the permission is correctly set

Comment: This should be the approved answer, it is much less time consuming and destructive than the first choice.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does not display OS level errors by default but this is most definitely a permission issue on your plugins folders in your site's wp-content/plugins.

You could enable debugging in order to see the original error which triggered the more generic one you've seen if you want to work with a better view of the world.

Multiple debugging options are documented in WordPress' [online manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). To enable debugging and log messages set the following variables in wp-config.php:

1. Enable debugging via WP_DEBUG

   - define('WP_DEBUG', true);
2. Enable logging debug messages to the /wp-content/debug.log file with WP_DEBUG_LOG

   - define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

You should probably make sure to disable these options and delete the debug.log file after gathering enough information as they could contain server information you do not want to be accessible publicly through your WordPress installation.

Alternatively we can try to guess what the most plausible cause can be:

> If you installed your plugins manually on the server and not via the
>   WordPress administration console it is likely you did it as a
>   different user then the one who is executing WordPress' PHP code and
>   thus requires proper access to perform such OS operations.

Finally the solution may be to fix the permissions or upgrade the plugins manually.

Comment: This didn't produce any extra debug information in my case (Wordpress 4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is permission issue.
and you will have to provided or make FTP user as owner of the plugins folder.

Most of the cases where you will be using same user for WordPress install and run as well as FTP access. If you are using different users for both above purpose then providing ownership to FTP user will fix this issues just like that.

**Ex:**

```
chown -R ftpadmin /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins
```

Hope this would be helpful if any body at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to delete the old plugin than update
If you have SSH access to your blog
Login your site via SSH.
Use SSH commands to nagivate “../wp-content/plugins/”.
type the given command to see all files and folders in the plugin folder

```
    ls -al
```

Search for the particular plugin folder in the list.
Next, type the given command to delete that folder.
In the command, replace the folder name with your plugin folder name which is you want to delete.

```
    rm folder name
```

now you're able to delete your old plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Hi this is the permission issue at wordpress so follow this command

> sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/thewayivogue/wp-content/plugins

like this where `thewayivogue` replace to your folder name.