# Wordpress JsonAPI - /wp-json/ was not found on this server

Tags: json, wordpress, openshift

I am using the following plugin [Json Rest API](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/).

To test the plugin the [documentation](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/master/docs/guides/getting-started.md) states that I should just use:

```
$ curl -i http://testpress-maxximus.rhcloud.com/wp-json/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sat, 24 May 2014 07:01:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Content-Length: 303
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /wp-json/ was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at testpress-maxximus.rhcloud.com Port 8
0</address>
</body></html>
```

As you can see nothing is found by the URL. Any recommendations if there is a problem with the API or wordpress?

I appreciate your reply

Comment: Do you have [pretty permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks) enabled?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The current version of REST api for sites with pretty permalinks not enabled, the url

```
    yoursite.com/?rest_route=/
```

will work .

Comment: @Foad it needs preety permalinks enabled

Comment: @DrDeo  Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress

Comment: Its probably worth noting that this url will work  whether permilinks are enabled or not, so if you are unable to know, then this is the safer option to use

Answer (score 44):

The WordPress JSON API [depends on pretty permalinks](http://wp-api.org/#rest-api_installation), make sure you have them enabled for the site.

Comment: aka - go to **Settings > Permalinks** and change the setting to **"Post name"** to get it to work for you. I would be cautious about doing this if you already have a live site as it will modify a lot of your urls.

Comment: But see the comment by @Mohammad AlBanna https://stackoverflow.com/a/57403026/516537

Comment: I had permalinks set to post-name already but was seeing the error. So I switched to a different setting and then switched back to post-name which fixed it for me

Answer (score 33):

In my case, I got this error after installing/configuring apache2 on my local linux machine.  I finally found the error to be cause by the rewrite module not being enabled which I fixed using,

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

as well as ensuring that my apache2.conf file (located in the folder /etc/apache2) has its`<Directory>` directive 'AllowOverride' set to all rather than none, from

`<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

to

`<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

then I restarted apache2 service and the problem was resolved.

Comment: how to do this if you have Bluehost as server?

Comment: you'll need to reach out to your support to get the apache configuration files.  Bluehost does not make it easy for you to access these files.

Comment: Thank You! It works!

Answer (score 29):

I have faced this issue several times . The solution is this :

Login into your Wordpress site: example.com/wp-admin

1. Then click on **settings**
2. Then click on **permalinks**
3. Then set permalinks to "**post-name**"
4. Save Changes

[image: Screen shot illustrating steps outlined above]

Comment: But see the comment by @Mohammad AlBanna https://stackoverflow.com/a/57403026/516537

Comment: Although it was already set, saving again fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes the solution is crazy and easy! Go to the permalink settings by moving to `Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks`...then just hit `Save Changes` without doing anything else! This refreshes the memory of WordPress.

Why is that? For a situation I had before, I had changed the main website URL so I had to refresh the permalinks as well.

Comment: I think this was just your situation, what is probably more important is what you had selected, perhaps "Post name"

Comment: @MaxCarroll this solution worked for me as well. I think it is more important to flush/reset the references. Clicking "Save Changes" affects database even if no visual changes are made.

Answer (score 9):

I had this same issue and wanted to post my solution in case anyone else comes across this answer and the other answers don't solve the issue, as this happened with me.

In my case I didn't have a `.htaccess` file with Wordpress' default `mod_rewrite` rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This solved the issue for me. Per the [documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/):

> WordPress uses this file to manipulate how Apache serves files from
>   its root directory, and subdirectories thereof. Most notably, WP
>   modifies this file to be able to handle pretty permalinks.

Comment: Perfect answer, but note that if this is the solution, you have a serious problem with your configuration. This can easily happen if you have migrated a WordPress installation to another place and forgot to do the stuff in one of the other answers: pressing "save changes" in settings->permalinks.

Comment: This worked for me as I was using `%postname%` permalink and was missing this file. I installed the site using Plesk.

Answer (score 3):

I was running WP on a local dev environment in a subdomain of localhost (eg mysite.localhost:8888)

The solution for me was to update the virtual host config in httpd-vhosts.conf to set directory options, similarly to Aurovrata's answer:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>    
    ServerName mysite.localhost    
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/mysite"    
    <Directory /Users/myusername/mysite>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All        
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar issue, turns out that Apache's mod_rewrite module wasn't enabled. Worked fine after enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue was due to the WP site being developed at the root of a staging URL (ie example.com) but when put live it was installed in a sub-directory (ie example.org/wp)

Before I could make [the suggestion from this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53929736/2917183) work I had to `chmod 664 .htaccess` to make it writable by Wordpress. I then resaved the Permalinks as suggested and Wordpress updated the `RewriteBase` in .htaccess to `/wp`

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly installed the plugin, be sure to flush the rewrite rules.

This can be accomplished with the wp-cli: http://wp-cli.org/commands/rewrite/flush/