# WordPress JSON API returns only 404 errors

Tags: json, wordpress

I'm brand new to `Wordpress` and I would like to use the `JSON API` plugin.

So I put it in my plugin repository and I activated it but when I try to display the `Json` response by accessing the `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/posts` url I get a `404` error.

I'm probably missing something but according to the documentation it should be that simple. Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842235/wordpress-jsonapi-wp-json-was-not-found-on-this-server/52719375).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong address. According to the documentation, the following are valid links:

**Implicit mode examples:**

- http://www.example.org/?json=1
- http://www.example.org/?p=47&json=1
- http://www.example.org/tag/banana/?json=1

**Explicit mode examples:**

- http://www.example.org/?json=get_recent_posts
- http://www.example.org/?json=get_post&post_id=47
- http://www.example.org/?json=get_tag_posts&tag_slug=banana

**With user-friendly permalinks configured:**

- http://www.example.org/api/get_recent_posts/
- http://www.example.org/api/get_post/?post_id=47
- http://www.example.org/api/get_tag_posts/?tag_slug=banana

Source: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

So in your case you should use `http://localhost/wordpress/api/get_recent_posts/`

Comment: Thanks, it works! I had read on the dashboard of Wordpress in the plugins page : "Want to get your site's posts? Simply send a GET request to /wp-json/posts" that's why I did this.

Answer (score 9):

It is an mod_rewrite issue.

Reason is one of these in your .htaccess:

- not existing
- wrong permissions
- screwed up

Try the [htaccess documentation on Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) for your .htaccess:

```
## BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly for me. Everything was working fine started facing issue suddenly only because of .htaccess file. Thanks a lot for saving my time.

Comment: when .htaccess, permissions and php extensions are ok, we can play with site configs. In sites-available conf folder I just added `<Directory /var/www/html/mysite/>` with `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` ,`AllowOverride All`. `Require all granted`. Reloaded apache and not 404 errors are gone. This solves elementor 404 error on `/wp-json/elementor/v1/globals`

Answer (score 6):

Old question and answer, but for anyone coming here recently via search results (like me), /wp-json/posts should at least bring a JSON result (albeit still a 404 error), and /wp-json should list some available routes in JSON.

If it doesn't (e.g. it shows an Apache or other 404 error page), it's probably a permalinks issue

Comment: You may need to use a different permalink structure. Encountered the same issue using the wordpress docker compose image. Use anything other than the query string method.

Comment: If I could I would spam the +1 button. This was why my plugin didn't work on a fresh installed wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

**/wp-json/elementor/v1/globals - 404 error**

Just update the plugin if any update is available and deactivate it first and then re-activate it again. The problem will be solved.

When we activate the **Elementor** plugin then this plugin creates some essential files for editing, so when we will re-activate it then it will re-create all essential files and our problem will be solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on whether you have NGinx or Apache.
On some hosts with Plesk if Nginx is used, Plesk does not create or re-create the .htaccess file, but for WP it must be present.
If it's not there, just recreate it with the standard WP settings https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/ as mentioned in one of the previous answers.

A workaround (insecure) is to create directories and files /wp-json/elementor/v1/globals with {} like Json standard, elementor will work the same, but I don't recommend doing that.