# page 404 wordpress not triggering

Tags: wordpress

I have installed 404 plugins, I even have a 404 page but I don't know why it is not showing.
My website is one page website and when it should display the 404 page it shows :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /asd was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at mysite.com Port 80
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: what 404 plugin did you install

Comment: I have deleted it now because I saw that our theme has a 404.php file and a place where you can customize it, but it is not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add handler for error page in .htaccess file

for example in htaccess file add this code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /your404page.php
```

Comment: Where is the htaccess file and what handler should I add?

Comment: @FlorinPop This is the correct answer.  [READ HERE](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)

Answer (score 1):

First check that you have a `.htaccess` file in your WordPress root folder (the one that contains your `wp-config.php` file). If it's missing, copy the following text ([source](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess#Basic_WP)) into a new plain-text file called `.htaccess` in the WordPress root folder. Also, [make sure this file is readable by Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18352682/1679849) (permissions of `0644` should suffice).

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If that doesn't help, then your Apache server doesn't support the use of `RewriteRule` directives. This is most likely because mod_rewrite isn't enabled for your particular domain. To fix this, you need to edit the Apache configuration file and add this line to the configuration statements that apply to your domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

The location of the Apache configuration files can vary depending on your hosting setup, but try looking for a file called `httpd.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf/`.

Check your server's error log too. There might be some useful information in there.

Comment: I added the .htaccess file and now when I put something like mypage.com/somethinghere it goes to mypage.com. How can I send the user to another page? for example mypage.com/404

Comment: You don't need to redirect to a different page. The page management is all done inside WordPress. When you visit `mysite.com/2015/01/`, for example, the .htaccess file redirects this request to `/index.php`. WordPress then examines the original request URI to decide what page to send back to the client. So for example `/2015/01/` might bring back a list of all the articles published this month. If WordPress can't find the requested item, it will reply using the file `404.php` inside the home directory of your current theme.