# What are the Correct WordPress Filesystem Permissions and Ownership

Tags: wordpress, apache, file-permissions

I've got a site hosted on an apache server VPS and I'm always running into problems with uploads, installing plugins etc.

The response I get from my web host is;

```
777 is the correct permissions for files/folders apache needs write access to
```

This seems to contradict with what the WordPress Codex says.

Can somebody explain why WP recommends 755 but my host is saying 777?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 755 for folders, 644 for files.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress  to get correct file permission in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress Codex has some good info for [hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions). Ideally, all files should have `644` permissions, and all directories should be `755` (no higher).

If you're still running into issues adding plugins and updating WordPress, you should heed the advice of the following (unless you want to enter FTP details into WordPress each time):

> Any file that needs write access from WordPress **should be writable by the web server**. If your hosting set up requires it, that may mean those files need to be group-owned by the user account used by the web server process.

Comment: I know WP recommends 644 and 755. What I don't understand is why my host would suggest 777.

Comment: Only your host can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you can't articulate a REASON for your own settings [which is fine!], I'd leave the permissions at 777. It can get confusing otherwise. So if you don't know the purpose of what you're doing, at least simpler seams better. PS - I manage dozens of sites and have 777 on everything.