# Wordpress www-data access permissions

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I read about this a lot of articles, but still cannot find a proper solution.

I'm maintaining a VPS on DigitalOcean, here I have few sites on wordpress.
The problem is that I don't know how to configure correctly the `wwww-data` group.

I created an user, let's name it `admin`, and all installation are under this user. When I'm accessing wordpress admin panel I'm not able to upload media, or plugins. This is because the folders permissions are 755, and the `www-data` doesn't have rights to write them.

Few weeks ago I had playing with the permissions, we got hacked, there was directly modified theme wordpress wiles with malicious scripts.

Can someone tell me how to configure correctly the `www-data` permissions, in order to be secure and in same time to be able to work properly with wordpress: add/remove media, manage themes and plugins?

I'm using Ubuntu 14, Nginx, Php 5.5

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Amazon AWS EC2. You can see this question - [Correct file permissions for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)

```
chown www-data:www-data -R *
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

But you should consider your security! Server permissions to all folders in Wordpress folder is dangerous. There should be more precise permission settings.

Comment: What might the more precise permission settings be?