# Ghost Blog Directory/File Permissions

Tags: unix, permissions, chmod, ghost-blog, chown

What are the recommended directory and file permissions for Ghost Blogging platform? I am looking a similar answer as in Wordpress at "[Correct file permissions for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)" but could not find any answers.