# File uploading fails: The file can't be moved

Tags: wordpress, file, upload

I'm developing a Wordpress website into a distant server but I have an error when I try to upload a file, like an image.

Here is a screenshot:

(PS: It's in French, but it means "The file can't be moved to wp-content/uploads/2016/04")

[image]

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: It's a common issue due to folder permissions. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress and to [Changing File Permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Comment: Unfortunelly my folder is already with the 775 permitions

Comment: All of them? `uploads`, `2016` and `04`? If they are, then you should check the owner/group, because it means _others_ permissions are applying. Also (but not recommended) you could set 777 to the folders.

Comment: I've juste checked the permissions of the folders included into Uploads and they've also the CHMOD in 775 value.

Comment: I resolved my problem. It was from my .htaccess. I add "php_value upload_max_filesize 64M" and "php_value post_max_size 64M" and it works pretty well !