# Wordpress plugin install: Could not create directory

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I'm using WordPress on centos 6.

I try to install a plugin. But I got this error:

> Installing Plugin: bbPress 2.5.9
>   Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/bbpress.2.5.9.zip…
>
> Unpacking the package…
>
> Could not create directory.

How can I resolve this?

P/S: I run this command:

```
sudo -u root touch /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/test.txt
```

and it works. But I still get that error.

Comment: test.txt is not a directory well it might be stupid what I write right now, but check if you can create a directory here. (just to make sure).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The user that is running your web server does not have permissions to write to the directory that Wordpress is intending to create the plugin directory in. You should chown the directory in question to the user that is running Wordpress. It is most likely not root.

In short, this is a permissions issue. Your touch command is working because you're using it as root, and root has global permissions to write wherever it wants.

Comment: Obviously, but that doesn't tell us which directory to fix.

Comment: @felwithe it's not obvious to OP, obviously.

Comment: it doesn't matter who you think it's obvious to or not (even though the error message literally says "couldn't create directory"), it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Fair enough. I was more trying to explain what the problem was so he could understand how to fix things like this in the future.

Answer (score 134):

You only need to change the access permissions for your WordPress Directory:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data your-wordpress-directory
```

Best practices:

```
sudo find /var/www/html/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html/wordpres/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

or

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Where `.` is the path of WordPress directory.

Comment: your-wordpress-directory = "wp-content"

Comment: In my case since I'm on a Mac it was `chown -R _www:_www wp-content`, actually `sudo chown -R _www:_www wp-content`.

Comment: "your-wordpress-directory" does not tell me which directory is needed for plugins. Changing ownership of every directory in my Wordpress installation is unsafe, overkill, and may break other things.

Comment: felwithe, the directory needed for plugins changes when the wordpress directory changes. `your-wordpress-directory` signifies the place where you placed wordpress on your server.

Comment: this is a bad practice and should be avoid.

Comment: I tried this on mac but I get tihs : 

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/word
chown: www-data: illegal group name

Answer (score 90):

You can fix this by using the following commands. You should first be in the root folder of Wordpress.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content/plugins/
sudo chmod 775 wp-content

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content/
```

Comment: This should be the answer, because it tells us which directories to fix and how to fix them.

Comment: It worked for me. If you purged apache2 and wordpress on ubuntu , you have re-apply those permissions

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS WORKED FOR ME

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. I'm using a WordPress docker container in Windows 10 WSL2.

Comment: Today i tried the same setting and I am not able to access my website. Getting connection time out error

Answer (score 17):

A quick solution would be to change the permissions of the following:

- `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content`
- `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins`

Change it to `775`.

After installation, don't forget to change it back to the default permissions.. :D

Comment: Great quick fix for users without root access

Comment: In my case it changed permissions for wp-content but it its not allowing to change for plugins for wp-content

Answer (score 11):

I had to give ownership of `/plugins` and `/upgrade` to the server, nothing else.

```
$ cd /var/www/wordpress/wp-content
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data /plugings
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data /upgrade
```

Running Apache server on Ubuntu 18.04. Maybe more dirs will need to be changed later. Anyways, I plan to restore permissions once I finish editing, as suggested in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25865028/6170136).

Comment: If other answers do not solve the problem, try this one! /upgrade directory is suspicious!

Comment: bad practice indeed.

Answer (score 11):

If you have installed wordpress using apt, the config files are split in multiple directories. In that case you need to run:

```
sudo chown -R -h www-data:www-data /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/
sudo chown -R -h www-data:www-data /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/
```

The `-h` switch changes the permissions for symlinks as well, otherwise they are not removable by user `www-data`

Comment: how i can change permission on cents os server

Answer (score 8):

To solve permission issue on plugins and themes on localhost or production quickly, you just run this

```
sudo chmod 757 wp-content/themes
sudo chmod 757 wp-content/plugins
```

if take care permission on production, you can run

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content/themes
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content/plugins
```

Answer (score 7):

CentOS7 or Ubuntu 16

---

#### 1.

WordPress uses `ftp` to install **themes** and **plugins**.
So the `ftpd` should have been configured to create-directory

```
vim /etc/pure-ftpd.confg
```

and if it is **no** then should be **yes**

```
# Are anonymous users allowed to create new directories?
AnonymousCanCreateDirs       yes
```

lastly

```
sudo systemctl restart pure-ftpd
```

#### 2.

Maybe there is an ownership issue with the parent directories.
Find the Web Server user name and group name if it is **Apache Web Server**

```
apachectl -S
```

it will print

```
...
...
User: name="apache" id=997
Group: name="apache" id=1000
```

*on Ubuntu it is*

> User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
> Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used

then

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache directory-name
```

#### 3.

Sometimes it is because of directories permissions.
So try

```
sudo chmod -R 755 directory-name
```

in some cases `755` does not work. (It should & I do not no why) so try

```
sudo chmod -R 777 directory-name
```

#### 4.

Maybe it is because of php safe mode.
So turn it **off** in the root of your domain

```
vim php.ini
```

then add

```
safe_mode = Off
```

NOTE:
For not entering **FTP** username and password each time installing a theme we can configure WordPress to use it directly by adding

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

to the **wp-config.php** file.

Answer (score 7):

If you are mac user , using XAMP

Go to the htdocs folder and open the terminal on the folder , as shown in the screenshot

[image]

Then Type the following command on the Terminal

```
**sudo chmod -R 777 <your wordpress folder Name>/**
```

E.g sudo chmod -R 777 wordpress/

Comment: This is very very dangerous

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the permission of the directory

1. At first change the user **HTML** folder (replace yourcomputerusername)

   `sudo chown yourcomputerusername:yourcomputerusername /var/www/html`
2. Next change the permission for the user

   `cd /var/www/html`

   `sudo chmod -R goa=rwx wordpress`

   or

   `sudo chmod -R 777 wordpress/wp-content`

Answer (score 3):

If anyone using shared hosting and get same problem it may be disk space issue. In that case contact with your hosting support and ask them to increase disk space of your acocunt.

Comment: same case. So cleanup a space

Answer (score 2):

I was on XAMPP for linux localhost and this worked for me:

`sudo chown -R my-linux-username wp-content`

Answer (score 2):

What I end up doing is every time I create a WordPress project. in /www/html

I run below command

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data  wordpress_folder_name -R
```

hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
sudo chmod goa=rwx -R /var/www/html
```

Comment: You should edit your previous answer (from almost a year before) rather than making a new one https://stackoverflow.com/a/65486715/2308683

Comment: bad security practice.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was FTP server that WP is using to upload update. It had writting disabled in configuration, so just enabling it fixed the problem.

Shame on WordPress for providing such misleading error message.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above work for me except this one.

`sudo chown daemon:daemon /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/`

Don't forget to change `/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/` to your directory

Comment: This is because every answer is for apache. You are using another distribution or server.

Answer (score 0):

Webserver user must have write access to directories to perform such operations, so you can try to change owner of files to webserver user (`apache` in this example, but can be differ from yours)

```
chown -R apache YOUR_BLOG_DIRECTORY
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation as to what this does?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some app that wraps http, you have to set these user in the command.

```
sudo chown -R [desireduser]:[desireduser] wp-content/
```

By example, if you are using lampp, the users that init httpd is "daemon" and the command that works will be:

```
sudo chown -R [desireduser]:[desireduser] wp-content/
```

You can search in your httpd.conf file
[image]

Answer (score -3):

> To solve permission issue on **ubuntu server**, you just run this
>
> ```
> sudo chmod 777 -R 'wordpress wp-content file location'
> ```
>
> for example.
>
> ```
> sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content
> ```

Comment: This is a bad idea, 777 gives access to all users and processes to write these files.

Comment: this is  your call how you use chmod, i just given the solution

Comment: If the issue happens on your local, it's fine to use 777.

Answer (score -4):

wordpressProject is the project name.

```
/var/www/html/wordpressProject sudo chmod -R 777 wp-content
```

Thanks. It will work.

Comment: never set 777 permissions unless u want to get hacked even by bots.

Answer (score -9):

Absolutely it must be work!

- Use this 
  `chown -Rf www-data:www-data /var/www/html`

Comment: You shouldn't give the webserver full control of the files in webroot.