# Can't install wordpress plugins locally using XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp

In reference to this question:

[Wordpress plugin install: Could not create directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157264/wordpress-plugin-install-could-not-create-directory/53930960#53930960)

Would simply comment but can't comment with less than 50.

I followed the instructions of updating permissions with chown using the following command:

```
sudo chown -R _www:_www wp-content/plugins/
```

However I get operation not permitted on a long list of all the contents of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

The `FS_METHOD` can be defined in `wp_config.php` like so:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.
Put in **functions.php**

```
if(is_admin()) {
  add_filter(‘filesystem_method’, create_function(‘$a’, ‘return “direct”;’ ));
  define( ‘FS_CHMOD_DIR’, 0751 );
}
```