# How to install plugin in wordpress after following error?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to install the wordpress plugin in my localhost wordpress. I am getting the following error whenever I try to install a new plugin.

Installation failed: Could not create directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the folder of the plugin and try to reinstall it again.
Or try this: [Wordpress plugin install: Could not create directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157264/wordpress-plugin-install-could-not-create-directory)
If you don't manage to setup the permission ask the hosting support to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't work yet.