# Not able to change wordpress directory directory permission on Ubuntu

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu

I am new to wordpress. I installed XAMPP server & wordpress successfully on my Ubuntu machine but I am not able to install any plugin or theme as it giving error that: `Installation failed: Could not create directory. /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/upgrade`

I tried to give permission to the directory as per this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157264/wordpress-plugin-install-could-not-create-directory) but still no solution.

My root directory is: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress`

My htdocs permission directory looks something like this:
[image]

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely true that permissions are a pain in the neck on Ubuntu XAMPP.

Try doing this:

```bash
cd /var/www/whatever-your-home-directory-is
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod a+w {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod a+wx {} \;
```

Then, when doing stuff to files from your shell, precede your commands with `sudo -u www-data`. For example, to delete the debug log file do this.

```bash
sudo -u www-data rm wp-content/debug.log
```