# Correct permissions for /wp-content/ files?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, geoip

When adding GeoIP.dat to WordPress backend would you set the permissions to 744 or something else?

I am trying to get WooCommerce to work correctly on my site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct file permissions for WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)

Comment: Normal 644 is just perfect

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution, make Apache the owner, then set permissions

```
chown www-data:www-data  -R *  

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```