# Trouble migrating a wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress

I just finished migrating a wordpress website into a new website (hosted on godaddy's managed wordpress). Here is what I did:

1. Exported the database using this plugin:
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/
2. Changed my site-url and home-url to the new ones
3. Did a search and replace for 'wp_' in the exported db for the correct 'wp_xxx' in production
4. imported the backup into prod.
5. copied over the entire wp-content onto the new server.

Everything worked well except for two issues that I ran into (wondering what happened):

1. The first issue was with the pages templates. While the pages (in
   the db) and templates (in the source) were transferred just fine. I
   lost the association of page -> template. I had to go in to the
   production dashboard and re-select the pages' templates.
2. Something happened with all my media. Basically, the media files
   moved over just fine to the prod server but when I go into the
   wordpress dashboard > media, they all appear like gray files. Also,
   I cannot add them to any posts (as featured images). However, if I
   grab the media item's url and just paste it into my address bar, it
   is shown just fine (which means that they are where they are
   supposed to be on the server, and the server is serving them up).

I just don't understand why these issues occured. Where could I have lost information given that I moved over all of wp-content and the entire db?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a file permission error. Can you verify your uploads/media folder has 744 permission?

Comment: @Ryderpro Can you expand on that?

Comment: (http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-image-upload-issue-in-wordpress/) This has a good walkthrough of changing file permissions on the folder.

Comment: @Ryderpro Ok, do you think the template issue is related to this as well?

Comment: Been a couple years since I've migrated wordpress sites. Could be. You may want to switch to default theme and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Another item to check. Which user/group owns wp-content. This is a good SO answer on [permission issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23755604/3675145). When transferring the files permissions can get lost.

Comment: @Ryderpro Thanks a bunch.