# VPS FTP access to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, vps

I've set up a VPS with LEMP on Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Wordpress with [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-16-04)
How can I setup a FTP account to access my Wordpress files?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user (for FTP access) with its home directory as the web root.

E.g

```
useradd -m -d /var/www/html USERNAME
```

That will create a user with the web root as its home directory.

Then you can sort the password out:

```
passwd USERNAME
```

And then use an FTP server like vsftpd and it will work when you log in.

You might have to mess with the permissions a bit. E.g adding the user to the web server group and giving the files and folders correct permissions.

https://www.ostechnix.com/install-vsftpd-server-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

For permissions see this 
[Correct file permissions for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)

You might need to tweak the groups etc depending on what you setup.