# Edit Page save button not showing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

my website was running smoothly without any issue but after a long time now I opened admin panel to edit a page but there is no save/publish button is available and also the WYSIWYG controls are also not visible. I tried on Chrome/Firefox/IE/Opera but all browsers are getting same issue. I replaced the post.php file in /wp-admin, but no change happen and the problem remain.

Following is the screenshot of page editor:

[image]

What is the way to resolve this issue?

Comment: It is hard to say what the issue is without being able to debug on the site but I would guess this is an issue with a plugin you have installed.
Troubleshooting JS conflicts: check the browser console for errors and post screenshots here.
Troubleshooting PHP issues: open up your `wp-config.php` file in the root directory of your site and add a new line above where is says "/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */" with this code: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`. You should then see any error messages with PHP problems toward the top of the screen when you reload the edit page.

Comment: Also you can try clearing your browser cache and cookies and see if that fixes the issue. I am seeing that answer on a lot of forums...

Answer (score 0):

According to the date of this question which belongs to 6 months ago, I think it's resolved now anyhow! But I just try to share my similar experience.

> For my case, the hosting company had some update and migration. In
>   their new configuration, the Permission/Ownership of the WordPress
>   directory did not match with the new web server configuration.

I had to change all the permissions of files to 644 and I had to make sure all the directory got 755.

You should have 'root' access to the server or ask your hosting company to fix it. Also, it's better to [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress) as well.