# Wordpress unable to upload files, update plugins, access htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, chown

I have the following issues showing up out of nowhere in my Wordpress blog, really hope someone can help me as it’s been driving me nuts for weeks!

Showing up in my admin dashboard at the top of the screen:
Plugin Leverage Browser Caching: htaccess file is not readable or writable. Please change permission of htaccess file. --- permissions are set to 644

Whenever I try to update a plugin:
Update Failed: Could not create directory. -- the plugins folder is set to 755 in terms of permissions

Whenever I try to upload an image:
 exceeds the maximum upload size for this site. (It's set high in php.ini and .htaccess)

I’m sure they are all related as they all showed up at the same time. I have a feeling that I’m having owner issues which is causing WordPress to not have access to my htaccess file, plugin folder, media uploads folder, .. But that being said I don't know anything about owner issues or how to fix them.

Thanks to anyone who can help me fix this nightmare!

Comment: It's a file/folder permission issue. Get in touch with your hosting provider and ask them to have a look at your files/folders permissions (or follow niklas' advice, read that article and adjust the files/folders permissions yourself).

Comment: I asked them about it already and they suggested that I change it all to 777, wasn't the most solid advice I'd ever gotten :D All the files/folders are set correctly though, checked it a few times to make sure

Comment: _(...) they suggested that I change it all to 777_ ... you really, really should consider moving your site to another hosting. Yours clearly doesn't care about security :/ With that said, even though the permissions might be right, there's a chance that the user (aka "owner") Apache uses to interact with the filesystem (assuming your hosting is using Apache) doesn't have enough permissions to write to it.

Comment: I feel like that's exactly what's wrong - the owner permissions, any idea how I can fix it? I saw a few chown commands before but they all looked different and I didn't want to risk using the wrong one

Comment: This might help, @Lisa: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23755604/9131961 (make sure to read the comments and adjust your permissions accordingly).

Comment: If you're using cPanel, I remember it had a "Fix permissions" function somewhere. Maybe that can help, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should take time to read to this great post on the [official Wordpress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).

Comment: Already read it unfortunately, all the permissions are set correctly according to that documentation :)

Comment: Hey @niklas, since the URL might change/404 in the future (rendering your answer useless for future readers), maybe you should add the actual instructions directly here instead of just sharing a link to that page.