# Theme Editor Stylesheet File Editor Error in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to change CSS of my wordpress website. I am changing code under wp-admin/theme-editor.php. But whenever i click on upload file button, an error appears `Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and upload the file over FTP.`

I thought this happened because of plugin, so i deactivate all the plugins and tried again. But problem was still there. Does any one know how to solve this problem?

I also installed [Health Check & Troubleshooting](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) to find the error. Here is snapshot of health check https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uwJg.png

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all I suggest you to use FTP and proper `.php` file editor for editing your WordPress site.
2. Secondly - you should never make changes directly to WordPress core files as they may overwrite during update.
3. Lastly - **the error is probably due to file permission error**. Go to FTP and set your WordPress **folder permissions** to `755`, all **file permissions** to `644` and set `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php` file permissions to `444`. This will fix your issue.

P.S. Here is short tutorial I found on Google. This will help you to fix this issue: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-fix-file-and-folder-permissions-error-in-wordpress/

Comment: @Jack then file owner is probably set to one that has no permissions. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress