# uploading jpg to wordpress site gives permission denied

Tags: wordpress, image

I'm trying to upload an image via Wordpress, I get an HTTP error. When I use FileZilla, it gives "permission denied" error.

When I right click the folder "uploads" and choose file attributes,

[image]

it shows 755 and I change it to 744 including sub folders. Then press OK.

[image]

But then I get an access denied:

[image]

Comment: You need 755 permissions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress

Comment: 755 is what is was. And that didn't work.