# Can anyone tell me what the command for SSH is to reset all WordPress files and permissions?

Tags: wordpress

I apologise for the basic question, but I am quite new to SSH and it is a bit difficult. I used

```
chmod -R 755
```

but it seems to reset all the files to 755 as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a good SO question with excellent answers : [Wordpress Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct file permissions for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

first :

```
chmod -R 644 *
```

second :

```
 find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
```

i hope it works