# Images are not displaying in wordpress library "No media files found" error id displaying when I inspect the page

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I tried to upload an image in my wordpress admin. its not displaying on the library.

1) I tried plugin enable and disable.
2) I tried edit permalink.

Comment: The upload is working? Are the images on your server after the upload?

Comment: Yes images are on the server. but not displaying in the library.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

1. A permissions error on the wp-content folder [SO question on setting permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)
2. Max Post Size - In your admin go to tools -> site health -> info -> server and confirm your max post post size is larger than the image. Its set in php.ini
3. Invalid format - Wordpress limits some formats like svg, but typically you'll get an error.