# Localhost works but refuses to connect on a particular project (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE) (WAMP)

Tags: wordpress, import, migration, localhost, wamp

this is my third question about the same project, so yes, i'm struggling. 
I'm trying to manually import a wordpress site in local. We don't have access anymore to the dashboard (some bad stuff happenning), so i can't install a plug-in that migrate the site easily and automatically.

After having problems for linking the database with the site, i had PHP errors (continue targetting to break). Now i don't have php errors anymore but i can't access the site anymore.

I can go to localhost, it reaches it easily, i can go to my other projects, but it refuses to reach this particular project.

It says :

```
This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I've traveled on different forums to find a solution but i didn't find why it occurs only on one of my projects. The only difference i see is that the other projects use mariaDB and this one MySQL.

thanks for the help

Comment: 1. When you say manually import, do you mean using the WordPress Importer plugin?

Comment: I mean that i copy the OVH folder, and then i import the database. I change the wp-config.php file with the new database infos, and here i am

Comment: Wow, okay. It could be a number of things (the most obvious being the **.htaccess** misconfiguration) especially when moving from different servers. Did you follow the steps listed here [Moving WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/) or some similar list of instructions? And are you moving between servers or between folders?

Comment: Yes i followed the steps written on this site. I had php errors due to versionning, and i already had this problem where i couldn't reach my site, but it would eventuallly fix when i restarted the wamp server. Now it does not work anymore if i restart the services. I'm moving from ovh to local. 
Thank you for taking your time to respond !

Comment: Exactly as I though. The server you're moving from might be using different php,apache,mysql etc. versions so it will actually cause you to do a lot of headaches & running around if you don't know what you're doing. Unfortunately for you I can't debug your local setup vs your OVH setup so what I would suggest you do is go back to your OVH installation and use a plugin like [duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to move your website. I know it's not really the solution you're looking for but it will save you a lot of time so you can get back to coding.

Comment: OK thanks for the answer. I don't have access to the dashboard that's why i 'm trying to import the site manually. We re in litigation with the customer and this is very touchy.

Answer (score 0):

Dude,
check local on flywheel its much simplier than wamp. Link:
https://localwp.com/

besides when migrating manually:

1. zip all ur files and download
2. install new wordpress in your local machine.
3. copy somewhere new wp-config.php and save it in different localization
4. paste and extract zip package in new wordpress localization on your computer
5. download database from wordpress you want to migrate on your local machine
6. replace wp-config.php which u extracted from files with your new wordpress instalation wp-config.php [ad.3]
7. it would be nice if u install wp-cli on your computer:
   link for windows:
   https://www.ryadel.com/en/install-wp-cli-windows-wordpress-command-line-interface-how/
8. import database into your new wordpress and than run search replace in order to change migrating site domain name [use wp cli its easiest way]
    
   to import DB:
   https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/import/ 
   to replace domains:
   https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/
   *remember that your DB need to be .sql and pasted in main wp directory*
   *open terminal in main wp directory and write than wp-cli commands*
9. If u re not familiar with terminal on windows I prefer gitbash / its easy to use adding linux commands and all sort of staff (always remember to open as administrator)
   u can download here:
   https://gitforwindows.org/
10. after performing all this actions you can now log-in into wordpress on your local machine.
    go to settings->permalinks and click save.
11. here you go u have finally migrated your site!
12. If you see 'error technical issues' you should also check ur file and directory permissions of wordpress.
13. here a link to correct permissions You can change with in gitbash terminal:
    [Correct file permissions for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. this is the steps i followed to import the site, even if i'm not using the tool that you recommand here. I may try again with that, but this seems to be a versionning problem so i don't know if it's going to fix it.

Comment: Also u should change plugin folder name to plugin_old. And check if WP is working. Sometimes plug-ins causing the problem. It also can be server configuration. Good luck.