# What is the recommended file permissions that I can set for my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

We are using AWS for WordPress site hosting. Now I want to know what will be the correct file permissions for WordPress files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct file permissions for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

The article on [Hardening WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/) also has a chapter about the [file permissions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#file-permissions) you should set.

Basically it's 755 for folders and 644 for files, speaking in `chmod()` terms.

Answer (score 0):

These are recommended permissions from the community.

- wp-content    755
- wp-content   755
- wp-includes  755
- All .php files   644
- All folders  755
- wp-config.php (public_html folder)   400/440
- index.php (public_html folder)   444/644

You can notice wp-admin is not included in the above list. The reason is, experts recommend wp-admin should be outside of the www/htdocs/public_html.