# Is it safe to give wordpress SSH access for updates?

Tags: wordpress, ssh

In ubuntu I have the `/var/www/wordpress` folder owned by a user. In order to update/upgrade wordpress some folders need to be owned by `www-data`.

I am kind of confused but from what I've read that may pose a security risk. So I keep all the files owned by the user and when I need to update, I log to ssh (using pubkey), do a `chown -R www-data /var/www/wordpress` and after update I `chown -R user:user /var/www/wordpress`.
The trouble is that I cannot auto-update wordpress and have to do all this manually.

I found about [Enabling SSH Upgrade Access](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#enabling-ssh-upgrade-access) and can't figure out if this is safe security wise.
Giving wordpress access to public and privatekey would compromise it?

```
define( 'FTP_PUBKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' );
define( 'FTP_PRIKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to give the WordPress an SSH access for updates. and also if the website get hacked the hacker could get access to modify your php files and add new ones. Whatever you do if the website get hacked you gonna face files permission problems but you can protect from thus hacks by telling apache to not execute any php file that go under `wp-content/uploads`

What you can try to do is the following
`sudo chown -R user:www-data /var/www/wordpress`
and add this line `define(‘FSMETHOD’, 'direct);` in your wp-config.php
that would allow WordPress to autoupdate the plugins/themes/core without using the SSH access.

You can check more about my answer [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/allowing-wordpress-to-update-install-with-ssh-keys)

Comment: Some are saying [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress) that is not safe to give www-data permission to own the wordpress directory

Comment: if you wants the WordPress to auto-updates its core you need to give www-data access to the WordPress directory, to secure your website more add configuration on apache/nginx that no php file under wp-content could run and with this way you block the hackers from accessing your server by just uploading a php file