# A siteurl or homeurl definition was detected in your wp-config.php, but the file is not writable

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I am facing this error in WordPress, how can I solve it? It will be displayed on the main page of the counter
""A siteurl or homeurl definition was detected in your wp-config.php, but the file is not writable. Set your wp-config.php to writable and reload this page.""
More information is directed to this [link](https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/htaccess-wp-config-files-not-writable/)

I have no information about this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct file permissions for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)

Comment: Also, ensure wp-config.php is not protected by a security plugin. Further, check htaccess for a specific rule.