# Wordpress/apache2 - AH01797: client denied by server configuration

Tags: php, wordpress, apache2

I've recently updated my Ubuntu server to 22.04 but I have some issues when trying to modify my Wordpress site, I'm just getting:

`You don't have permission to access this resource.`

And when I look in the apache2 error log I can see:
`[access_compat:error] [pid 1619605] [client 185.224.57.161:58465] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/example/wp-admin/customize.php, referer: http://www.example.com/`

This is my apache site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    <Directory /var/www/example>
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/example/wp-admin>
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp user=username group=username threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /create /var/www/flask/flaskapp.wsgi
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/word_error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

I have given access to files like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23755604/3332023

running: Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu)

This is how the error file looks, and what PID that is denied etc.

```
[Thu Oct 12 15:45:52.657776 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 3070059] [client 217.116.228.14:60801] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/example/wp-admin/post.php, referer: http://www.example.com/
```

To see what what user tried to execute it I used:

> ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'

```
www-data    1254  0.0  0.0   7852   184 ?        Ss   okt08   0:13 /usr/bin/htcacheclean -d 120 -p /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk -l 300M -n
root     3070052  0.0  0.2 320480 38108 ?        Ss   15:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070053  0.0  0.1 320468 16932 ?        S    15:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
user     3070054  0.0  0.1 447824 24268 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070055  2.0  0.5 333164 82232 ?        S    15:45   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070056  1.8  0.5 406980 82828 ?        S    15:45   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070057  1.6  0.4 331108 79460 ?        S    15:45   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070058  1.6  0.4 333176 79548 ?        S    15:45   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070059  1.5  0.5 335504 88984 ?        S    15:45   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070116  2.2  0.6 435444 100364 ?       S    15:45   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070268  1.8  0.4 333116 79548 ?        S    15:45   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070346  1.4  0.4 329064 77984 ?        S    15:45   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070371  1.3  0.4 330824 77372 ?        S    15:45   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3070372  1.4  0.4 329000 76768 ?        S    15:45   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
user     3072180  0.0  0.0  12088  2488 pts/0    S+   15:46   0:00 grep -E --color=auto (apache|httpd)
```

So 3070059 was running by the `www-data` user, to see what permissions is set I used:

> ls /var/www/example/ -lh

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  15K okt  8 08:37 about.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4,0K jun 23 04:00 backup_1
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   39 jun  1 03:26 classsmtps.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  405 feb  6  2020 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  20K jan  1  2023 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  31K jun 23 04:00 mah.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 6,0K jun  1 03:26 mds.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 7,3K jul  5 19:41 readme.html
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4,0K jun 23 04:00 saiga
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 7,1K maj 12 23:35 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data 4,0K aug 29 16:14 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  351 feb  6  2020 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 2,3K jun 14 16:11 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 3,4K okt 10 08:53 wp-config.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 3,0K feb 23  2023 wp-config-sample.php
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data 4,0K okt  9 13:34 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 5,6K maj 30 20:48 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 28 www-data www-data  12K aug 29 16:14 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 2,5K nov 26  2022 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 3,9K jul 16 14:16 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  49K jul 17 15:18 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 8,4K jun 22 16:36 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  26K jul 25 08:35 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  34K jun 19 20:27 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 4,8K jun 22 16:36 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 3,2K jun 14 16:11 xmlrpc.php
```

Comment: what output do you get for ```sudo -u www-data namei -l /var/www/example/index.php``` ?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x root     root     /

drwxr-xr-x root     root     var

drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data www

drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data exempel

-rw-r--r-- www-data www-data index.php

Answer (score 0):

first find out what user your PHP runs as, on linux you can find out by running `<?php var_dump(shell_exec("id"));?>`

By default on Ubuntu, it's the `www-data` user, so i will refer to it as the `www-data` user below.

Next make sure www-data owns all the files in `/var/www`:

```
sudo chown -Rv www-data:www-data /var/www
```

next we need to make sure all the directories are executable and writable and readable by the www-data user:

```
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod -v u+rwx {} \;
```

next we need to make sure all the files are readable and writable by the www-data user:

```
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod -v u+rw {} \;
```

that should fix your permission issue :) glhf

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried to change the file permissions as suggested but it didn't help. I updated my question with some more info regarding this.